# Snippet load only one page?

Tags: wordpress, loading, code-snippets

How to make that snippet using (Code Snippet in Wordpress) load only one page, because of home page and other pages loading time.

The code I'm using:

```
   '''add_action( 'init', 'register_uzleteim_endpoint');
   
/**
 * Register New Endpoint.
 *
 * @return void.
 */

    function register_uzleteim_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'uzleteim', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'uzleteim_query_vars' );

/**
 * Add new query var.
 *
 * @param array $vars vars.
 *
 * @return array An array of items.
 */
function uzleteim_query_vars( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'uzleteim';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_uzleteim_tab' );

/**
 * Add New tab in my account page.
 *
 * @param array $items myaccount Items.
 *
 * @return array Items including New tab.
 */
function add_uzleteim_tab( $items ) {

    $items['uzleteim'] = 'Üzleteim';
    return $items;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_uzleteim_endpoint', 'add_uzleteim_content' );

/**
 * Add content to the new tab.
 *
 * @return  string.
 */
function add_uzleteim_content() {}
```

I'm already tried something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
    if ( ! is_page( array( 42, 'Page Name', 'about-us', 968 ) ) ) return;

    // rest of snippet code here

} );
```

But it was not work, cause "unexpected if"

Comment: Your last snippet should work. Where are you placing this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_page() {

global $post;

if( $post->ID == 18) { ?>

      <!-- do your stuff here -->
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_page');
```

Comment: It looks nice. My post ide is 3009. This is my account.

id 3009 - my account
my account/shoplist.  - no id

Can we do something?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to obtain. 
Hook on page 'my account/shoplist' or on a specific id account?

Comment: A page, but my account/shoplist created with a snippet, so there is no own ID and 3009 not work.

Comment: Does my account/shoplist have a specific body class? If yes you can hook on that body class directly.

Comment: I mentoined under the "The code I'm using:", that was the code with created. It is a Woocommerce MyAccount Tab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53600003/11982309